# SUMIF with HSTACK

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have this table.My goal is to generate a single cell report using Array formuals.

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 3/1/2023 | 0 |
| 3/3/2023 | 2 |
| 5/1/2023 | 8 |
| 5/5/2023 | 11 |
| 5/9/2023 | 14 |
| 5/12/2023 | 14 |
| 5/16/2023 | 19 |
| 5/30/2023 | 0 |
| 5/31/2023 | 0 |
| 6/1/2023 | 2 |
| 6/1/2023 | 2 |
| 4/18/2023 | 3 |
| 4/28/2023 | 14 |
| 4/30/2023 | 14 |
| 5/1/2023 | 0 |

What I have tried so far is

`=LET(d,TEXT(Table1[Date],"mmmm"),v,Table1[Values],ud,UNIQUE(TEXT(Table1[Date],"MMMm")),s,HSTACK(ud,{1;2;3;4}),s)`

I want to use `SUMIF` inside `HSTACK` so as to obtain the result in the format as shown below.

| Month | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| March | 02 |
| April | 31 |
| May | 52 |
| June | 4 |

Any pointers? please

Answer (score 4):

Please look past the Dutch date notations, but have a try with:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(m,TEXT(SORT(A2:A16),"mmmm"),u,UNIQUE(m),HSTACK(u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(s,SUM(DROP(SORT(A2:B16),,1)*(m=s))))))
```

In `G1` I put the simplest Pivot Table which is probably what you should be using here.

Comment: Got very same formula and made very same mistake! You need to pass unsorted TEXT(A2:A16,"mmmm") in SUM(B2:B16*(m=s)) part: SUM(B2:B16*(TEXT(A2:A16,"mmmm")=s))

Comment: Woops, yes you are correct =), will quickly edit that

Comment: Can someone explain why simple SUMIF inside HSTACK doesn't work?

Comment: SUMIF input must be a range, plain range, like A2:A16. If you modify your input range with for example TEXT formula TEXT(A2:A16,"mmmm"), it returns array, and arrays are not accepted as SUMIF input. For example if you have month names in column A, SUMIF formula =SUMIF(A1:A5,"June",B1:B5) can be changed to more universal =SUM((A1:A5="June")*B1:B5). This kind of expression is used in answer

Answer (score 3):

Only an alternative approach, though the post says about the usage of <kbd>SUMIF()</kbd> with <kbd>HSTACK()</kbd> while any <kbd>IF()</kbd>'s family dont work with arrays as its known the syntax always starts with range and not with arrays, which actually clarifies the most of it. However, this is an alternative approach without any <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SORT(A2:B16),
     b, TEXT(TAKE(a,,1),"mmm"),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),DROP(a,,1))))
```

---

Or, if the header is needed then,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, SORT(A2:B16),
     b, TEXT(TAKE(a,,1),"mmm"),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     d,HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),DROP(a,,1))),
     VSTACK({"Month","Sales"},d))
```

---

One more thing, I would like to do instead of just getting sum of sales by months i would use months and years to have a proper comparison, if may in future the sales of previous years are added then it would not make any difference and mix up all the sales. However, it depends on ones requirement to show a report or presentation.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, SORT(A2:B20),
     b, TEXT(TAKE(a,,1),"mmm-yy"),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     d,HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),DROP(a,,1))),
     VSTACK({"Month","Sales"},d))
```

---

Comment: Formula EXACT() accepts only text as an argument but still works with array. Does it mean that we can not go with the formula syntax to know if a formula accepts array or not?

Comment: Re: **Formula `EXACT()` accepts only text but works with an array**, have you tried the same way in older versions yet?

Comment: Yes, CSE works with EXACT()

Comment: For that you need to select some amount of ranges to make the CSE work. Also without further ado, i would also suggest you before posting questions you should do some basic research here, since i found your present post and last post have already been asked quite a number of times. Very similar questions you have been asking, these questions are not first time it has been raised, please do research more

Comment: And to say about your first comment `Text` can be a range or an array, so there is no discrimination here at least, hope it makes sense to you. But @P.b. Sir has given you the exact solution you are looking for.

Comment: I appreciate your advice !. It is indeed the case that both my recent and preceding inquiries have been brought up on several occasions. However,it is worth emphasizing that each iteration brings forth distinct viewpoints and nuanced articulations. This diversity not only adds depth to our discourse but also fosters a more comprehensive grasp of the subject. You almost concluded that SUMIFS() don't work inside HSTACK but we can still see few clever workarounds that you don't see it in the similar questions. Neverthiless,I greatly appreciate your responses.I find your solutions to be excellent!

Comment: You should read minutely what I have posted. Any IFs family ie SUMIF() or SUMIFS() or COUNTIF() etc don't work with arrays. I didnt said it doesn't work with HSTACK().  While the solution given using SUMIFS() specifically uses ranges and not arrays, more specific structured ranges.

Comment: Thank you once more. You appear to have a firm grasp on dynamic array formulas. Could you kindly share which resources have aided you in achieving this level of proficiency?

Answer (score 3):

While you have an explanation and 2 posts showing good solutions, I wanted to show that SUMIFS, in this case, could still be used inside LET:

```
=LET(a,Table1[Date],
     m,UNIQUE(SORT(MONTH(a))),
     d,DATE(2023,m,1),
HSTACK(TEXT(m*28,"mmmm"),
       SUMIFS(Table1[Sales],a,">="&d,a,"<"&EDATE(d,1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Single-cell formula with only one array input needed:

```
=LET(
    array, A1:B16,
    dates, DROP(array, 1, -1),
    months, MONTH(dates),
    sales, DROP(array, 1, 1),
    headers, TAKE(array, 1),
    VSTACK(
        headers,
        HSTACK(
            UNIQUE(TEXT(SORT(dates), "mmmm")),
            MAP(
                UNIQUE(SORT(months)),
                LAMBDA(m, SUM(N(months = m) * sales))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]